# What are CLOCK, RESET and ENABLE signals collectively called?

Tags: verilog

I want to add a comment before CLOCK, RESET and ENABLE signals.
Is there a good collective term for these signals?

```
(
  // ???
  input CLOCK,
  input RESET,
  input ENABLE,

  // Interconnect
  output [15:0] ADDR,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [CPUs](http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/mdp_micro/lecture1/lecture1-3-1.html), we tend to describe there being 3 buses between the CPU and other components - the Address Bus, Data Bus and Control Bus.

Here, these seem to be Control signals, so that's what I'd go for.